# Decoding new access_token from google oauth login response

Tags: reactjs, oauth, google-oauth

I am using the package [@react-oauth/google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google) package for authentication in my react app.
According to it's docs, if I use `<GoogleLogin onSuccess={...} />` component, then I receive `credential` in the response from which I can easily decode the user information.

```
<GoogleLogin 
     onSuccess={(res) => {
        console.log(res);
     }}
/>
// Response
{credential: 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjhlMGFjZjg5MWUwOTAwOT…u5AjExZ4f6zvn8P-SZB4V0vTtQo-nXkR2ela_1foHoKXzCWDA', clientId:'626778026017....apps.googleusercontent.com', select_by: 'btn'}
```

But If I want to use my own custom button, then I have to use `useGoogleLogin` hook. Doing so, I get `access_token` in the response and facing difficulties decoding user information.

```
  const login = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: async (response) => {
      console.log("Res", response);
    },
  });
 return (
    <Button onClick={() => login()}>
    ...

// Response 
access_token: "ya29.a0...nw0163",
authuser: "0",
expires_in:3599,
...
```

I have tried sending that token to my backend server and using the `verifyIdToken` function provided by `import { OAuth2Client } from "google-auth-library"`. But it gives the error like: `Wrong number of segments in token ...`

Am I missing something?

Comment: To get the user information you need to either go though the google People api or the userinfo endpoint.  The access token just gives you access to get data it doesn't contain any claim data.   I think it used to but not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In token flow, you can't get JWT but also you don't need to get it to get user profile info.
Google gives you `access_token` to talk with their APIs

```
const googleLogin = useGoogleLogin({
  onSuccess: async ({ access_token }) => {
    const userInfo = await axios.get(
      'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo',
      { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}` } },
    );

    console.log(userInfo);
  },
});
```

** userinfo response **

```
{
    "sub": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "name": "Mo'men Sherif",
    "given_name": "Mo'men",
    "family_name": "Sherif",
    "picture": "xxxxxxx",
    "email": "xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
    "email_verified": true,
    "locale": "ar"
}
```

In code flow yes you can, all you need to exchange code to get access_token, refresh_token and id_token (id_token is the JWT that has all info about the user)

Client

```
const googleLogin = useGoogleLogin({
  onSuccess: async ({ code }) => {
    const tokens = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/auth/google', {  // http://localhost:3001/auth/google backend that will exchange the code
      code,
    });

    console.log(tokens);
  },
  flow: 'auth-code',
});
```

Backend (using express)

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const {
  OAuth2Client,
} = require('google-auth-library');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
  process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  'postmessage',
);


app.post('/auth/google', async (req, res) => {
  const { tokens } = await oAuth2Client.getToken(req.body.code); // exchange code for tokens
  console.log(tokens);
  
  res.json(tokens);
});

app.listen(3001, () => console.log(`server is running`));
```